# How to reference a custom flutter package published as universal package in Azure devops feed

Tags: flutter, package, azure-artifacts, hosted

So i have developed a package say A and published in Azure devops > Artifacts >Universal Package.
In my pubspec.yaml file of the project i am referring it as

```
`dev-dependencies
A:
  hosted:
    url: https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectname}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedname}/Packages/
    path: packageA
    ref: v1.0.0`
```

Reference : https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#hosted-packages (Hosted PAckage in custom repo)
I have also created a PAT token and set as environment variable. also used command as below
 `dart pub token add https://feeds.dev.azure.com --env-var MY_SECRET_TOKEN`
MY_SECRET_TOKEN  is saved in environment variable.

I get an issue:
Because flutter_appp_Example depends on package 'A' any which doesn't exist (could not find package A at  [https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{projectname}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedname}/Packages/](https://feeds.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bprojectname%7D/_apis/packaging/Feeds/%7Bfeedname%7D/Packages/))

I am expecting that it refers the package from the repository directly and i dont have to run command for downloading universal package which looks like below:

`az artifacts universal download --organization https://dev.azure.com/ericsson/ --project="Integrated_Service_Flow" --scope project --feed Mobile_Feed --name my-first-package --version 0.0.1 --path .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not supported to use DevOps universal package in the pubspec.yaml file of your flutter project.

The dependencies sources in pubspec.yaml support below:

[image]

And for Hosted packages, it supports custom package repository. The package should be able to fetch from the hosted-url.
[image]

However, DevOps Univeral feed package is NOT stored in the git repository, and cannot fetch from the feed package url. Hence, cannot use the hosted-url as the sample above.

Comment: So is there any other way where I can simply download my main project with a command and all dependent custom packages get installed. ? I have seen few custom repository service on flutter docs but does it integrated with Azure CI/CD pipeline.?? Really need  a help here. If anymore clarification please let me know

Comment: The DevOps project git repo and Universal package are two different parts, i'm afraid there's not a simple command to download all. For Universal package, have to use azure cli `az artifacts universal download` to download currently.